# php code to print multi dimensional array list values one by one

Tags: php, arrays

I am reading excel data and storing it in php multi dimensional array. I would like to print multi dimensional array list values one by one as given in expected out put...

**Php Code**

```
   $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
$i=0;
 foreach($sheetData as $rec)
{
    for($j=0;$j<4;$j=$j+1)
    {
     echo $rec[$i][$j];
    }
    $i=$i+1;
}
```

**Actual Out put:**

> nothing displayed
>
> **var_dump($sheetData)** shows as follows
>
> array(4) { [1]=> array(4) { ["A"]=> string(10) "First Name" ["B"]=>
>   string(9) "Last Name" ["C"]=> string(11) "Nationality" ["D"]=>
>   string(6) "Gender" } [2]=> array(4) { ["A"]=> string(5) "AGNI" ["B"]=>
>   string(6) "namera" ["C"]=> string(5) "india" ["D"]=> string(1) "M" }
>   [3]=> array(4) { ["A"]=> string(4) "QUEEN" ["B"]=> string(5) "fefar"
>   ["C"]=> string(5) "india" ["D"]=> string(1) "M" } [4]=> array(4) {
>   ["A"]=> string(7) "MASTER" ["B"]=> string(5) "patel" ["C"]=> string(5)
>   "India" ["D"]=> string(1) "M" } }

**Expected output:**

```
----------------
First Name
Last Name
Nationality
Gender
-----------------
AGNI
NAMERA
INDIA
M
------------------
...and so on...
```

Comment: Can you `var_dump($sheetData);` and paste here?

Comment: @user007:  array(4) { [1]=> array(4) { ["A"]=> string(10) "First Name" ["B"]=> string(9) "Last Name" ["C"]=> string(11) "Nationality" ["D"]=> string(6) "Gender" } [2]=> array(4) { ["A"]=> string(5) "AGNI" ["B"]=> string(6) "namera" ["C"]=> string(5) "india" ["D"]=> string(1) "M" } [3]=> array(4) { ["A"]=> string(4) "QUEEN" ["B"]=> string(5) "fefar" ["C"]=> string(5) "india" ["D"]=> string(1) "M" } [4]=> array(4) { ["A"]=> string(7) "MASTER" ["B"]=> string(5) "patel" ["C"]=> string(5) "India" ["D"]=> string(1) "M" } }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues here... the first is that you are trying to access indexes on `$rec` as if it is `$sheetData`.

The line `foreach($sheetData as $rec)` means "loop through the array, and create a variable `$rec` each time which references the the current item in array `$sheetData`. So when you try to call index 0, 1, 2, etc. on `$rec`, they don't exist, which leads me to the second point...

In your `for` loop, you are trying to access items via their index as a numeric, when they are indexed by a string (A, B, C, D, etc.) For example...

```
<?php

$numeric = array('foo', 'bar');
$strings = array('foo' => 'bar');
```

In the first example, `$numeric[0]` will return `foo`, while `$numeric[1]` will return `bar`. In the second example, there is only one item in the array, with index `foo`. It would be accessed by `$strings['foo']`. Trying to access `$strings[0]` would return a notice because the index does not exist.

You should be doing this like so:

```
<?php

print "----------" . PHP_EOL;
foreach($sheetData as $rec)
{
    foreach($rec as $part)
    {
        print $part . PHP_EOL;
    }
    print "----------" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

You should probably read up on [arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Also, if you got no output when running your script, you should probably set your error reporting level to E_ALL in your PHP configuration during development.

Comment: Thanks.. what is the meaning of null and true in  "toArray(null,true,true,true)"

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo "------------"."<br>";
foreach($sheetData as $ind)
{
    foreach($ind as $index=>$val){
        echo $val."<br>";
    }
    echo "------------"."<br>";
}
```

Comment: @logan It's worth noting that in @user007's example, the `foreach($ind as $index=>$val)` line basically means "For every item in the array `$ind`, create a variable containing the index `$index` containing the item's index, and a variable `$val` containing the item's value.

Comment: Thank you guys... what is the meaning of null and true in  "toArray(null,true,true,true)" in my question ?